# Compile-time error in uninstanciated function template

Tags: c++, templates

My understanding of function templates has always been: if they contain invalid
C++ and you don't instanciate them, your project will compile fine.

However, the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void contains_compile_time_error(T&& t) {
    int j = nullptr;
}

int main() {}
```

Compiles with:

- `x86-64 gcc 11.2` and flag `-std=c++20`;
- `x64 msvc v19.31` and flag `/std:c++20`;

and does not with `x86-64 clang 14.0.0` (with flags `-std=c++{11,14,17,20}`):

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'std::nullptr_t'
    int j = nullptr;
        ^   ~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Even more confusing to me, the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

namespace ns {
struct S {};

template <typename T>
void apply(T&& t) {
    //print(std::forward<T>(t));
    ns::print(std::forward<T>(t));
}

void print(S const&) { std::puts("S"); }

}  // namespace ns

int main() {}
```

Does not compile with:

- `x86-64 gcc 11.2` and flag `-std=c++20`;
- `x64 msvc v19.31` and flag `/std:c++20`;
- `x86-64 clang 14.0.0` and flags `-std=c++{11,14,17,20}`;

(all of them complaining that `print is not a member of 'ns'`) but does compile with `x64 msvc v19.31 /std:c++17`.

If I call unqualified `print`, then the code compiles with all the above compilers.

So, my questions are:

- is my understanding of function templates wrong?
- why do the above compilers behave differently with the code snippets I posted?

---

**Edit 0:** as per Frank's comment, `x64 msvc v19.31 /std:c++17 /permissive-` fails to compile function template `apply` where I call the qualified `ns::print`.

Comment: At the very least with regard to msvc. That specific compiler is notorious for evaluating templates particularly lazily. It still keeps that behavior by default to this day to avoid breaking old codebases. You need to use the `/permissive-` compiler option to bring it into "standard conformant" mode

Comment: iirc when any instantiation would be ill-formed then the compiler may diagnose it as error but it must not. In your second example `print` is only declared after you try to call it

Comment: Yes, your understanding (from the first paragraph) is wrong, which leads to the question: where does this understanding come from? There’s a lot of bad teaching material for C++ out there, but this is the first time I’ve heard this particular misunderstanding (I think).

Comment: The understanding is only *partly* correct. The code can be invalid for some Ts (which are then never used), but there must be at least **one** type T for which the code would be valid. The compiler is *allowed* to diagnose cases where it can tell that *all* Ts would fail (like when the invalid code doesn't even depend on T).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding of function templates has always been: if they contain invalid C++ and you don't instanciate them, your project will compile fine.

Nope, if the code in the template is invalid, then so is the program.

But what does "invalid C++" mean? You can have syntactically valid C++ that is still invalid semantically, and the semantics of C++ are highly contextual.

So there's multiple levels of "valid" that can be checked at different times during compilation, based on the available information. Critically, there are things that *can* theoretically be checked early, but are potentially unreasonably difficult. Because of this, compilers are allowed some leeway when it comes to validating the semantics of template definitions. However, **whether the code is broken or is not ambiguous, it's a compiler's ability to detect broken code that is.**

> why do the above compilers behave differently with the code snippets I posted?

As far as `int j = nullptr` is concerned:

The program is technically ill-formed, but the diagnostics is optional. So The code is broken, but GCC is not breaking compliance by letting it through.

For example, if `S` only had private constructors, then `print(std::forward<T>(t))` would be flaggable as being broken since there is no possibly `T` that would make it valid. However, requiring compilers to be smart enough to determine this in all cases would be kind of mean.

For `print()`:

Lookups are a bit of a different matter, there are hard rules that are supposed to be followed.

There are three types of lookups involved here.

- Qualified lookups, such as `ns::print`
- Unqualified lookups **not** involving template parameters, which you'd get if you tried `print(S{});`
- Unqualified lookups involving template parameters, such as `print(std::forward<T>(t));`

Lookups are deferred for the third category, but must still be performed the same as non-template functions for the other two.

Note that the code still needs to be syntactically valid, even in the case of deferred lookups, hence why `typename` needs to be added when doing a dependent lookup of a type.

And as for MSVC allowing `ns::print`: That compiler is not compliant by default on this (and other) aspect of the standard. You need to use the `/permissive-` compiler flag to enforce compliance.

Comment: As one of the deleted comments said, `/permissive-` is set by default in Visual Studio 2017 and later.    You have to go out of your way to turn compliance mode off now.

Comment: @Frank, I meant _semantically invalid C++_. I believe the snippets I posted are all _syntactically_ correct, aren't they?